# Cannot use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() in Laravel manual query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a database driven website using Laravel 5.2. I am working with Laravel's manual query builder.

What I want to do is to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the first query and select `FOUND_ROWS()` in the second query. But it is not working properly. My code is below.

```
$param = array();
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `report_items`.`id`,`items`.`name` as `item_name`,`items`.`id` as `item_id`,`items`.`item_code`,`report_items`.`created_at`";
$sql .= ",`users`.`name` as `username`,`users`.`id` as `user_id`";
$sql .= " FROM `report_items` INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.id=`report_items`.`item_id`";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id`=`report_items`.`user_id`";
$sql .= " WHERE 1=1";

$sql .= " LIMIT ?,?";
$param[] = (int)$offset;
$param[] = (int)$limit;

$rows = DB::select($sql,$param);
$count = DB::select("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `row_count`")[0]->row_count;
```

As you can see, I want to retrieve found rows in the second query. But it is not working as expected.

The first query is actually returning 3 rows. But when I retrieve the result from the second query, the number of rows is always 1.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Isn't it possible that laravel closes the connection to the db after each select() call and opens it again?

Comment: So there is no ways to retrieve numbers of rows ruturn ? In codeigniter $this->db->num_rows() . So how can I do it in laravel for manual select query ??

Comment: Can you try without `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and with `COUNT(*) as found_rows` in the first `SELECT` query? @Shadow - I'm not 100% sure but it'd make no sense to open/close MySQL connection. If it did, the framework would suck balls since it would be slow as snail if it did that.. from what I can tell, looking at MySQL's `show processlist` after performing queries via Laravel - the process id doesn't change. Every new connection gets a different id, so it indicates that it's not closing/opening on every `select` or request.

Comment: @N.B. I do not know laravel, but the behaviour would be consistent with this approach. Btw opening and closing db connections for mysql is not that costly as for example for oracle. It's just a guess on my behalf, I would check it out.

Comment: Using COUNT(*) and running similiar two queries is I think it is poor in performance.I mean I have to retrieve all records to get the count. Then run second query again with LIMIT. I want to avoid it. That is why I think about SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. @N.B

Comment: @WaiYanHein have you every found a solution to to using `FOUND_ROWS() ` in Laravel without making a second query?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to update your Laravel now. Because your code is working in Laravel 5.5 and higher.

Also you can get FOUND_ROWS using query by Model. For example:

```
$rows = User::query()
    ->select([
        DB::raw("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id")
    ])
    ->where("active", 1)
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();

$count = DB::select("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `row_count`")[0]->row_count;
```